# How can I run this JavaScript snippet only once when a user logs in?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple JavaScript snippet.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    swal("Hello!", "Welcome to Portal", "success");
};
</script>
```

How can I only run this if the page URL is `http://portal/?init` i.e. do not run it when the page URL is `http://portal` or `http://portal/?something_else`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `location.search` of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.search == "?init"){
    window.onload = function(){
        swal("Hello!", "Welcome to Portal", "success");
    };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check:

- `location.href` (full page url) or
- `location.search` (url query parameters `?...`) or
- `location.hash` (url hash `#...`)

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists("init",$_GET)){
      ?>
      <script>
      window.onload = function(){
        swal("Hello!", "Welcome to Portal", "success");
      };
      </script>
      <?php
    }
?>
```

You can also set a session when the user logs in, that way you can really run the script only once, even when the user refreshes the page:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists("userLoggedIn",$_SESSION)){
      ?>
      <script>
      window.onload = function(){
        swal("Hello!", "Welcome to Portal", "success");
      };
      </script>
      <?php
      unset($_SESSION["userLoggedIn"]);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use **document.URL**:

```
<script>
if(document.URL == 'full url goes here'){
    window.onload = function(){
            swal("Hello!", "Welcome to Portal", "success");
    };
}
```